# padding zeros after decimal in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring, padding

i have a table like

```
[A]-----------[B]
[0]-----------[0.012345]
[1]-----------[0.002345]
[0.2145]----[0.1457]
```

I need both columns A and B to be padded with zeros at the end upto 9th place after decimal
so the output should look like:

```
[A]--------------------[B]
[0.000000000]-----------[0.012345000]
[1.000000000]-----------[0.002345670]
[0.214500000]-----------[0.145700000]
```

NOte: total number of digits = 10 not including '.'decimal

Comment: What are the column types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE([A] VARCHAR(20),[B] VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
('0','0.012345'),('1','0.002345'),('0.2145','0.1457')
```

All you need to do is cast these values as `DECIMAL(10,9)` for more information about `Decimal` data type <kbd>[Read here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)</kbd>

**Query**

```
SELECT CAST([A] AS DECIMAL(10,9)) AS A
      ,CAST([B] AS DECIMAL(10,9)) AS B
FROM @TABLE
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═════════════╦═════════════╗
║      A      ║      B      ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 0.000000000 ║ 0.012345000 ║
║ 1.000000000 ║ 0.002345000 ║
║ 0.214500000 ║ 0.145700000 ║
╚═════════════╩═════════════╝
```